# Fundamental database design scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

**Problem definition:** a company wants to measure customers satisfaction of their products by asking some questions. company's prducts data stores in "products" table, customers data of each product stores in "customers" table and questions of each product stores in questions table. As simple as below:

> products: [ id, name ]
>
> customers: [ id, product_id(fk), name ]
>
> questions: [ id, product_id(fk), text ]

the question is, how can we design a table to store answers of each customer by considering that each customer can only answer its product's question. For example, if your answer is something like this:

> customer_answer:[ id, customer_id(fk), question_id(fk), answer ]

then its wrong because if our table's sample data is like the following:

> products: [ 1, "Chair" ], [ 2, "Table" ]
>
> customers:[ 1, 1, "Anthony Quinn" ], [ 2, 2, "Marilyn Monroe" ]
>
> question: [ 1, 1, "Any suggestion for this product ?" ], [ 2, 1, "How
>   do you estimate this chair ?" ]

then there **might be** a possible row with below data:

> customer_answer: [ 1, 2, 1, 'No, thanks' ]

that is wrong, because the customer with id #2 don't have the product_id #1, so it can be wrong table for this problem.

What can we do in such situations ?

it doesn't matter but BTW I'm using mysql for solving this problem.

Comment: You validate your data entry.

Comment: A customer can only be questioned about a product once?  What if they order a product on one date, and are happy with it, but order a second one later and have problems with it?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: its not matter in this question.

Comment: @DaveNewton: You mean using "on insert" trigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of surrogate keys hurting, rather than helping, your database design.  Also, you should probably have a separate Customers table to uniquely list customers.

Here's a quick design that removes the surrogate keys from the tables in which the existence of the surrogate keys makes it harder to enforce referential integrity.  The critical change is that CustomerProducts (what I've renamed your Customers table) now uses CustomerID, ProductID as the PRIMARY KEY, making it possible to enforce the integrity of the relationship between answers and products owned.

```
 Products:         ProductID, Name 
                       (PK = ProductID)
 Customers:        CustomerID, Name 
                       (PK = CustomerID)
 CustomerProducts: CustomerID, ProductID 
                       (PK = CustomerID, ProductID)
                       (FK = CustomerID REFERENCES Customers)
                       (FK = ProductID  REFERENCES Products)
 Questions:        ProductID, QuestionText 
                       (PK = ProductID, QuestionText)
                       (FK = ProductID REFERENCES Products)
 Answers:   CustomerID, ProductID, QuestionText 
                       (FK CustomerID, ProductID REFERENCES CustomerProducts)
                       (FK ProductID, QuestionText REFERENCES Questions)
```

Note: If you feel uncomfortable using the large VARCHAR field QuestionText as part of the PK on Questions and the FK on Answers (especially since the contents may change), you can reintroduce a surrogate key here or, perhaps better, add a column QuestionNo to provide ordering of questions within a single product; then make ProductID, QuestionNo the primary and foreign key.

Comment: the problem is, each customer have only 1 product. What about this problem ?

Comment: Ah, that's even easier (hard to believe, but easier ;-)).  Get rid of CustomerProducts and move the ProductID and its foreign key back to customer.  Then, create a new, UNIQUE INDEX on Customers(CustomerID, ProductID). Finally, the FK in Answers that references CustomerProducts should now say `REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID, ProductID)`.

Comment: Ok, good. I want to know what is the problem of Vikdor's answer? What the advantage of your answer ? (your answer is correct too)

Comment: They're now fairly similar answers, except that Vikdor left out any link between the answer and the question (you don't need a link if there's only ever a single question per product, otherwise you do).

Comment: @LarryLustig : can you please answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933877/relational-database-design-scenario) too if you can, its similar.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a foreign key constraint on customer_id and product_id in the customer_answer table referencing the id and product_id columns in the customer table to enforce storing answers to only customer's questions.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_answer
(
    id  INT,
    customer_id INT,
    product_id INT, 
    answer VARCHAR(128),
)
ALTER TABLE customer_answer
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Customer_Answer_To_Customer FOREIGN KEY (customer_id, product_id) REFERENCES customer(id, product_id)
```

Comment: can you please rewrite customer_answer table ?

Comment: Please see the update with the alter table statement to enforce the foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Note 2 FKs on `CustomerQuestion` table: FK1 `{CustomerID, ProductID}` and FK2 `{ProductID, QuestionID}`

[image]

Comment: in CustomerProduct table there is a problem that each customer have only one product and we cant add 2 product for a customer

Comment: @linker -- do not quite understand. Is that a specification that customer can have only one product?

Comment: yes, I think Larry's answer is what I'm looking for. Really thanks for your great answer, I learned new things from your answer. Yours is correct too. (they are same)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the job of the application data layer (the model in a MVC architecture for instance) to make the necessary checks before inserting the data.

Comment: I know we can check it in our business layer , but I'm asking to know is there any way to do this in out "data layer" of my application ?

Comment: Why on earth would one purposefully build a database and *ignore* the ability of the database to enforce referential integrity?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try writing a MySQL Trigger on Insertion of "customer_answer" which will check that the new combination (Product ID and Customer ID) what you are trying to add is there in the customers table or not, if yes then go ahead, if not you can revert.